# How to create a (procedural) ring mask for a 2D object

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes, procedural

It's been a minute since I've used Blender, so the title might not be right. I'm trying to create a texture using (preferably procedural) nodes that will create a mask on this ring:

[image]

that looks like this:

[image]

so I can achieve this effect (with the dotted rings):

[image]

I tried using layer weight and its similarities, but I kept getting a line going through the center of the entire circle rather than running around the middle of the ring.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you're after, but it may be more economical to *imply* the ring-gradients in the dot-size of your final effect:

[image]

.. which gives you some handles for animation, too.. (The Mapping node pushes the 2D texture through Z for the sparkle):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Lastly, I'm not sure where to begin trying to mask the mesh with the accessories onto the plane. The reference image shows that the arrowheads do not interact with the sparkles, which I can't seem to mimic. Here is a picture of what I'm talking about: https://imgpile.com/i/9L2jLk
.
I'm thinking about using a boolean with an intersect to get _something_ close to this, but I don't think it would work since neither the plane nor the arrows touch.

Comment: @Draco1660 Hi! That would depend on your workflow, I think.. whether you want it all in one material, or geometry, or post .. if one material, the most straightforward would be a UV-mapped image texture as a B/W mask between a solid color and the animated sparkles? One more mix, on the cascade. Just noticed though, no bloom on the foreground motif. I think that might corner you into the compositor. EEVEE bloom can't select.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this node setup should meet your needs.

[image]